# Induction motor - d-q model

Tags: induction-motor, electric-machine

I would like to simulate an induction motor in Matlab/Simulink using the d-q model.

I have found a paper that describes the whole procedure but I have this problem.

I am trying to create this block :
[image]

This block defines the following equation.

[image]

I can not figure out what the parameter *u in the matrix gain stands for and how this block defines the equation.

Edit: I do not have the Simulink model. The pictures are screenshots taken from the paper that I study.

Comment: Double click on block itself, or search in help document of library, it should be documented there.

Comment: @Deep , the pictures that I posted are screenshots from the paper. I don't have the Simulink model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`u` in Simulink indicates the input signal of the block, therefore the gain of that block is `KS`. I would expect KS to be the matrix you have in the equation, but we can't know for sure from the screenshot.

What you can guess is that, as an 3x1 array of `van`, `vbn` and `vcn` is given as an input to the block, and an 1x2 array with `vqsS` and `vdsS` is returned, the gain should be a 2x3 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

As @clabacchio said, u stands for the input of the gain.

In addition, Simulink lets you select this option as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75824/discussion-on-answer-by-yiannis-s-induction-motor-d-q-model).

Answer (score -2):

Go to Simulink library in Matlab, get this matrix gain block and check the parameters.

Comment: The OP stated that he/she does not have access to the model.